# MySQL + NodeJS, SELECT return undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Estou tentando retornar o `SELECT` do MySQL para fazer uma listagem, porém, quando dou um `return` para a função retornar o resultado do `SELECT`, a variável em que guardei esses dados fica com o valor `undefined`, segue exemplo abaixo:

**JS:**

```
sqlQuery(dbConnection)

function sqlQuery (dbConnection) {
    dbConnection.query('SELECT * FROM printers', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) return console.log(error)
      dbConnection.end()
      console.log(results)
    })
  }

// Neste exemplo, o console.log lista os valores normalmente:
/*
[
  RowDataPacket {
    ID: 1,
    nome: 'Ender 3',
    producer: 'Creality'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID: 2,
    nome: 'Tarantula',
    producer: 'TEVO'
  }
]
*/
```

Já quando tento retornar os valores dessa função e armazená-los em uma variável, acontece o seguinte:

**JS:**

```
const results = sqlQuery(dbConnection)

console.log(results) // undefined

function sqlQuery (dbConnection) {
    dbConnection.query('SELECT * FROM printers', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) return console.log(error)
      dbConnection.end()
      return results
    })
  }
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é porque a função `sqlQuery` não tem retorno, ela recebe como parâmetro um callback que será executado de forma assincrona, ou seja, quando a consulta tiver o resultado pronto, executa a função passada, mas continua não retornando nada

Você pode criar a variável fora e setar seu valor dentro do callback:

```
sqlQuery(dbConnection)

const queryResults

function sqlQuery (dbConnection) {
  dbConnection.query('SELECT * FROM printers', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) console.log(error)
      dbConnection.end()
      queryResults = results
  })
}

console.log(queryResults) // undefined
```

Observe que mesmo assim `queryResults` continuará com o mesmo problema, isso porque o log é executado antes do callback, que leva alguns milisegundos até ser executado (porque é assíncrono)

Você pode resolver isso com uma promessa:

```
const results = sqlQuery(dbConnection)

function sqlQuery (dbConnection) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dbConnection.query('SELECT * FROM printers', function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) {
              console.log(error)
              //Rejeita a promessa
              reject(error)
          }
          dbConnection.end()
          //Conclui a promessa
          resolve(results)
      })
  })
}

console.log(results) // Promise
results.then(console.log) // Os valores
```

Outra forma é usar `async` e `await` mas por baixo dos panos também é uma promessa

Answer (score 3):

O que ocorre é que o Node trabaha de forma assíncrona, ou seja, quando você executa a função "sqlQuery" ele não aguarda o retorno, ele já executa a linha seguinte. Por isso que o retorno é "undefined".

Para aguardar o retorno, você precisa utilizar Async/Await.  O seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
const results = await sqlQuery(dbConnection);
console.log(results);

async function sqlQuery (dbConnection) {
    try {
      const resultado = await dbConnection.query('SELECT * FROM printers');
      dbConnection.end()
      return resultado
    } catch (err) {  
        return err;
    }
}
```

Aqui tem mais informações:

https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628

Comment: Uma observação, dessa forma, quando um erro acontecer irá retornar o erro como se fosse o resultado esperado, uma função `async` retorna uma promessa, que possui os métodos `then` para quando ocorreu tudo como o esperado e `catch` para quando ocorre um erro, como está o erro será retornado no `then`, que espera algo diferente de um erro. Como seu `try catch` só retorna o valor ele deveria ser retirado, caso queira, por exemplo, logar no console o erro antes de retornar, pode manter mas causar a excessão dentro do `catch`